# Building tinycbor module with Zephyr

Tags: cbor, zephyr-rtos

I'm attempting to test use of tinycbor in the zephyr hello_world application sample in Zephyr 2.1.0.  I've added the flags below to prj.conf and make succeeds.  However, it does not appear to be pulling in any of the tinycbor sources and any references to  are unrecognized.

My installation has west and the tinycbor source files are available in "$ZEPHYR_BASE/../modules/lib/tinycbor".  How do I get the make system to find and build tinycbor?

prj.conf:

```
CONFIG_TINYCBOR=y
CONFIG_CBOR_PARSER_MAX_RECURSIONS=10
CONFIG_CBOR_FLOATING_POINT=y
CONFIG_CBOR_WITHOUT_OPEN_MEMSTREAM=y
CONFIG_CBOR_PRETTY_PRINTING=y
```

Answer (score 0):

`tinycbor` is automatically linked in if [`mcumgr`](https://github.com/zephyrproject-rtos/mcumgr) is configured, but up to now (zephyr v2.1) it is not implicitly configured if set up as in your scenario.

Add the following instruction to `CMakeLists.txt` file of `hello_world` application:

```
zephyr_library_link_libraries(TINYCBOR)
```

Comment: I presume you mean CMakeLists.txt instead of prj.conf.  I found I also needed to add `set(ZEPHYR_EXTRA_MODULES $ENV{ZEPHYR_BASE}/../modules/lib/tinycbor)` after including boilerplate.cmake for it to work.